# Why won't my computer let me greet my customers?

Tags: recursion, f#

I am writing an application to replace our technical support department. When a customer needs technical support, we will simply mail him a floppy disk containing this application, which he can simply put into his computer hole and install it. They just type in their problem and the program will output the solution.

I tried writing it in F#, but F# doesn't like it. I wrote this simple recursive function that shows a greeting message to the customer, but F# tells me "no, this code is bad". I'm quite confident that my code is good, and can't figure out why F# thinks it's so bad.

This is my code:

```
open System

let rec GreetCustomer message =
    let DisplayMessage message =
        Console.WriteLine(message + " " : string) |> ignore
        GreetCustomer
    DisplayMessage(x)

Console.WriteLine("Please do the needful by telling us your name?");
let CustomerName = Console.ReadLine()

GreetCustomer("Hello,")(CustomerName)("!")("How")("to")("help")("you")("today?")
```

and F# tells me

> Type mismatch. Expecting a     'a     but given a     'b -> 'a     The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a' and ''b -> 'a'

Of course the resulting type is infinite. I want to be able to chain the method calls up to an infinite number of times. I don't understand why F# doesn't like infinite types; I can write the same program in Javascript without any issues:

```
GreetCustomer = function(message) {
  DisplayMessage = function(message) {
    document.write(message + " ");
    return GreetCustomer; 
  };
  return DisplayMessage(message); 
};

CustomerName = prompt("Please do the needful by telling us your name?");

GreetCustomer("Hello,")(CustomerName)("!")("How")("to")("help")("you")("today?");
```

and it has exactly the output I want:

> Hello, Peter ! How to help you today?

If it works in Javascript, surely there must be a way to do it in F#.

How can I fix my F# program so that it won't complain about infinite types?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679547/function-which-returns-itself

Comment: "we will mail him a floppy disk" - you're joking surely.

Comment: Computer hole? That's downright hilarious.

Comment: `but F# tells me "no, this code is bad"` - could you quote the Compiler Error code with that? I think your locale translation of the message is making this hard to google

Comment: @sehe I use a Visual Studio plugin that simplifies all of the compiler error messages. It makes things so much easier for me to understand when it just points at a line and says `"no, this code is bad"` instead of spitting out some incomprehensible programmy-jargon message.

Comment: Sorry for the bad news, but the compiler is right, your code is bad :-). Fortunately, F# is not JavaScript. Maybe if you provided more motivation (why do you want recursive type?) then someone could give you the usual F# way of solving the problem...

Comment: *Checks date*: it's not April 1st, so what *is* this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question I linked in the comments elaborates on this extensively. There are ways to do this in F#, but none will give you the syntax you want. The following answers are about as good as it gets.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679547/function-which-returns-itself/2684005#2684005
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679547/function-which-returns-itself/2679578#2679578

In short, this is a limitation of type inference. As the compiler complains, the type of a function which returns itself cannot be solved; it's infinite.

#### EDIT

This is my preferred workaround (combining answers from the question I linked):

```
type Inf<'T> = delegate of 'T -> Inf<'T>

let rec makeInfinite f = 
  fun x -> 
    f x |> ignore
    Inf(makeInfinite f)

let (+>) (inf:Inf<_>) arg = inf.Invoke(arg)

let GreetCustomer = makeInfinite (printf "%s")

GreetCustomer "Hello " +> "there, " +> "how " +> "are " +> "you?" |> ignore
```

Comment: Infinite shminfinite! F# should be able to handle infinite types more elegantly than that.

Comment: This feels somewhat related to higher-kinded types, and I would love to see both them and cyclic definitions supported.

Comment: @Peter : That would require that .NET itself support infinite types. Don't blame F# for .NET limitations. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn - There's nothing preventing F# from doing this in .NET - the compiler creates subclasses of `FSharpFunc<_,_>` for function values anyway, so it could create a subclass `Inf<'b> :> FSharpFunc<'b, Inf<'b>>` for this function value.  The question is whether there's any realistic scenario that warrants it.

Comment: @kvb I just gave an example of a realistic scenario that warrants this. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The answers that Daniel linked to should tell you how to work around the problem.

In principle, I think that it would be possible for F# to infer a type such as `('b -> 'a) as 'a` given your definition (which isn't valid F# syntax).  The related language OCaml provides a [-rectypes option](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora209.html) to allow the compiler to infer cyclic definitions like this, but as I understand it the flag isn't enabled by default because inferred cyclic types are almost always an indication that the programmer has made a mistake.